# Como instalar pacote de pull request?

Tags: git, github, npm

Estou querendo instalar um pacote npm `ng2-table`, mas com um [pull request que ainda não está mergeado no master](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table/tree/785f7b4ecd1833a92bc6c94024df3f14e2b0eb6a). 
Existe alguma forma de eu adicionar esse pull request no meu `package.json`, de forma que ele instale esse commit ao invés do master do repositório?

Comment: Você fez a implementação em uma branch de um fork seu, correto? Já tentou: npm install git://github.com/meurepo.git#minhabranch --save ?

Comment: Não foi de um repo meu. Eu peguei um pull request no próprio repositório do componente que eu tou usando, no caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver esse problema, basta fazer os seguintes passos:

> 1. Vá ao repositório do fork, no meu caso era [esse](https://github.com/eronalves/ng2-table/tree/development/components/table)
> 2. Clique para fazer download e no botão `Download ZIP`, clique com o botão direito e copie o link;
> 3. No `package.json`, substitua o local onde fica a versão pelo link;
> 4. Substitua o .zip por .tar.gz

Esse foi o caso que funcionou para mim, outra alternativa que vi foi apagar o `.zip` e substituir o `archive` da url por `tarball`.